# Want to add button at the bottom but with lowest index value

Tags: javascript, html

```
<button class="btn" onclick="func(0)" value="">abc</button>
<button class="btn" onclick="func(1)" value="">def</button>
<button class="btn" onclick="func(2)" value="">ghi</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function func(i){
        var btn= document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[i];
        console.log(btn);
        btn.style.color="red";
    }
</script>
```

I want to add new button every time, and want to display them on top. For adding them on top i need to change numbering till end
any solution to this. How new button[i] can be displayed on top

Answer (score 1):

Subtract from the number of buttons to count from the end.

```js
function func(i) {
  var all_buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
  all_buttons[all_buttons.length - i - 1].style.color = "red";
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" onclick="func(2)" value="">abc</button>
<button class="btn" onclick="func(1)" value="">def</button>
<button class="btn" onclick="func(0)" value="">ghi</button>
```